# Multi-line Command Prompt Command

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, command-prompt

I'm trying to create a script where it opens command prompt and navigates to a folder to run a batch job.

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k',
                  'cd/Program Files/PremiumSoft/Navicat Premium'
                  & 'navicat.exe -batchJob testJob'])
```

The two commands run fine independently but I'm not sure how to put them together and run them in the same script.

Comment: This is probably related more to `bat`-file writing and running commands in Windows' cmd, than to Python and `subprocess`.

Comment: It looks like you could do this without involving the cmd shell: `navicat = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramFiles'], 'PremiumSoft', 'Navicat Premium', 'navicat.exe');` `subprocess.Popen([navicat, '-batchJob', 'testJob'], cwd=os.path.dirname(navicat))`. Though I'm dubious about setting the working directory to a subdirectory of `Program Files`. Programs have no business writing data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to run multiple commands in one process, you will likely have to run `subprocess.Popen` with the `shell` parameter set to `True`:

```
subprocess.Popen('startcmd/kcd/Program Files/PremiumSoft/Navicat Premium&navicat.exe -batchJob testJob', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I had last week when I got it to work but did not save and couldn't figure it out.